# Creating Default Object From Empty Value CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got a legacy CodeIgniter (1.7) site that I'm working on. Upgrading to 3.x is not an option at the moment, but will be in the future. Currently having an issue with some of the bug fixes due to the old code base.

I'm receiving a "creating default object from empty value" error on the second line below. I'm assuming it's because $rec_update is not actually populated with a value.

```
$rec_update = $this->Basket->find($basketid);
$rec_update->price = $order_total * $quantity + $groupPrice;
```

$basket_id is set with this line

```
$basketid = $this->db->insert_id();
```

In the application the item is still being added to the cart, but due to the errors being thrown, my ajax notification is failing and never indicates to the user that the item was successfully added.

Any help is appreciated.

Pastebin with the entire Basket class https://pastebin.com/NDb85C8G

Comment: Can you show the `Basket` class

Comment: Pastebin added in the original question.

Comment: I'm not sure how things were in CI 1.7, where is `$rec_update` declared, what file? and did you load the `Basket` class in that file?

Comment: What exactly does "Basket::find()" return? The error message indicates that `$rec_update` is not set, is NULL or is FALSE.

Comment: Class is using PHP4 style constructor. Try with `public function __construct(){/*code from Basket method here*/}` instead `function Basket()`. Also change properties, move keyword `var` but give there visibility i.e. `public $CustomerId; public $ColsolidatedShippingCharges`.